# Excluding a directory in a maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

For one of my Spring-boot projects, i am using Spring Security. I use multiple sub directories, but csrf is not one of them. NexusIQ reports an issue with the classes from the csrf directory. I can waive the issue since i am not using it and the problem would be solved, but i am wondering if there is another way to exclude this folder from being in the dependency. A way to 'exclude' this directory from being downloaded in the first place.

Using the exclude tag i can exclude underlying dependencies, but i can't figure out how to use it on a folder. Is this possible?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: The folder structure from spring-security-web]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `I use multiple sub directories,`?

Comment: I use the server, session, access and method.annotation subdirectories. I want to cherrypick the folders instead of downloading the whole library.

Comment: Simple answer to this: No. as J Fabian Meier mentioned. You don't use directories you use a dependency which is in the end a jar. The jar itself has also other dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can either take the whole dependency or leave it.

The only way around this would be to compile the dependency yourself from source or to create a patched version of it by manipulating it.